# how to reference a reactive $ variable inside a svelte store?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I'll brief.

I have a reactive variable that updates everytime a user adds a product to a shoppingcart.

```
let cartItems = []
$: cartLength = cartitems.length;
```

Now I want to put the length of the cart items into icon in a different component. So I tried to create and share it with the rest of the component.

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export const cartItemsLength = writable("");
```

In my cartitems component. I tried to update the store after importing it into my component:

```
cartItemsLength.update(value=>{
value =  cartLength
})
```

But it shows undefined in my dev tools everytime. I tried $cartLength {$cartLength}
So, my question, how do you assign that cartLength variable to the value inside the store update function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

writable store's update function should have a return value to be set in the store.

https://svelte.dev/docs#writable

```js
// File cartitems.svelte

import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const cartItemsLength = writable(0);

let cartItems = [];
$: cartLength = cartItems.length;

// 1. use store's update function
cartItemsLength.update(value=> {
  return cartLength;
});

// 2. or you can just use $store if in .svelte script
$cartItemsLength = cartLength;
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed the return part.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to clear a store variable within the store, but I couldn't seem to access the store variable 'sessionData' directly, or by using '$sessionData' (because I used a .js file), so I created a variable and accessed that to clear the array variables.

```
<sessionData.js>

import { writable, get } from 'svelte/store';

export let sessionData = writable(
   { Record: { ID: "foo",  Name: "bar"}});

export const clearData = () => {
   let poSession = get(sessionData)
   poSession.Record.ID = "";
   poSession.Record.Name = "";
}
```

In your case you could (if you used a javascript file to hold your store) do -

```
<cartitems.js>

export const setData = (cartLength) => {
    let poCartLength = get(cartItemsLength)
    poCartLength = cartLength;
}
```